# How does a with clause effect the overall query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, dataset

I have a query that has a with clause like such,

```
select column1, column2,........., columnN
  from table1, table2, table3, ......, tableN
 where table2.uniqueIndex = table1.uniqueIndex
   and table3.uniqueIndex = table2.uniqueIndex
   and ...... tableN.uniqueIndex = tableN-1.uniqueIndex
```

Here in my query, N = 23.
When running this alone I get a runtime of about 1 minute. This is because is the data is very large itself and there is no filtering clauses that I have applied.
Now I want to apply a filter clause, say table1.primaryKey = xxxxxxx,
When I add this to the query I get a runtime of 0.197 secs which is nice.

However if I wrap the above query into a WITH block and then select from the subquery and then apply my filter clause, I get a runtime of more than 3 minutes.

Does oracle return the whole dataset of the subquery before it adds my filter when using the WITH statement.
Also I understand that oracle save WITH blocks as stored querys so as to not run it every time.
However, the data in my tables is everchanging and large, so should I not be using the WITH block to fetch this data and then apply my filters (user inputs)?

Essentially my query is slow, but it should not be slow especially when matching the primary key of one of my most important data table. The other tables are anyways small configuration tables.

Just want to understand how the WITH statement actually changes the efficiency and what are the 'never do' rules when using WITH clause (and why?).

Any documentation/tutorials is appreciated.

Comment: use standard sql joins the are around for 30 years. with makes temporary tables the same as slects make in the from clause and have therefore the same "problemes"

Comment: run an explain plan and post the results

Comment: SQL is declarative and you ask a database *what* you wand, not *how to* obtain that result. Optimizer is free to choose any optimization technique available. Subquery is not a separate step of the query, it's primarily a logical grouping. Oracle has [view merging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/query-transformations.html#GUID-6045D0F4-79A9-4688-A844-85F225DFA7DD) optimization which may (sometimes) lead to very different execution plan depending on the statistics available. Only *actual* execution plan may explain what's going on during execution

Comment: If the same CTE is used at least two times, such `with` subquery will be [materialized](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/query-transformations.html#GUID-C1AE164B-E99F-418A-9B2A-1ADB036048DF), which is not always a good choice.

Comment: Try using the INLINE hint in the WITH clause query to prevent materialization and promote view merging. Though, if you have to do that, you may need to reevaluate why you are using WITH in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, post an EXPLAIN plan for both the "fast" version and the "slow" version of the query. And post the actual queries - there may be relevant detail there.

As a blind guess... are you using the correct datatypes in both of your queries? If your column is VARCHAR2 but you are using a number (not a string) in your "fliter clause" predicate, then that could prevent use of the indexes you expect.

As for your expectation of how Oracle handles the "WITH" clause - it may materialize it, or it may not. Oracle does things the way it wants to. The plans should shed some light on this.

From what you described, the query using the WITH construct should perform just as well as the one that has the predicate imbedded in the query.

Comment: I was able to find the real problem.
The table I was filtering against was actually being outer joined in the inner query.
It seems like oracle does not do a 'predicate push' in this case.  Don't really know why, But doing an inner join fixes the issue, or keep the outer join and filter inside.